# JS not working in production env in rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Js is not loading in production environment. I have spent a day to solve this issue but all ended up in vain. Finally here I'm.

I have no issues in development environment.

My appication.js as

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

I've my production.rb as

```html
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  #config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://limitless-fjord-36968.herokuapp.com/'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "social_network_#{Rails.env}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Gem file:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'rails-controller-testing'
# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'rspec'
gem "paperclip", "~> 6.0.0"
gem 'figaro'
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

gem 'devise', '~> 4.4'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.2'
group :development,:test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'factory_bot'

  gem 'web-console'


end
group :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'

end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Application.html as

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= yield(:page_title) %> |Post</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track'=>'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true  %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
```

When i tried to deploy in heroku I see the issue in console as
[image]

I don't have anything like pt.each in my code

I also tried rake assets:precompile, yarn add jquery but still couldn't solve the issue. Any suggestions are most welcomed.

Comment: Looks ok to me, but I would exchange `rails-ujs` for `jquery_ujs` in application.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't use rail but Why not import .js file just before the closing body tag instead of the head tag.

Also ensure you check js dependencies are working and use mozilla or chrome source viewer to check the path whether it is valid or not.

Answer (score -1):

remove `//= require_tree .` from application.js and add each js file.

Comment: Okay. what is each js file ?

Comment: I meant to add all(each and every) js files in application.js . Did't meant any each.js file.

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake in my title. it's not file . Js is not working

Comment: I don't have any specific js files. I use js in my view

Comment: Did you find anything in the error log? can you post the error log

Comment: when i tried to deploy in heroku i don't see any error in logs. I've posted console error.

Comment: did you try `tail log/production.log` ?